# How can I prevent my array from becoming disordered? (AngularJs)

Tags: arrays, angularjs, sorting, object, resolve

I passed a series of objects by the "sort" function and ordered it correctly, but by sending the promise in angularjs with $d.resolve(myList), it seems that the order is lost again. How can I prevent this from happening?

```js
var deferred = $q.defer();
var requests = $q.all([getValue1(obj), getValue2(obj)]);

requests.then(function (values) {
    var toOrder = _.union($scope.values, values[0], values[1]);
/*
This are values
[
    { name: '11A.1C.8', value: 21 },
    { name: 'F1.8C.10', value: 37 },
    { name: '11A.2C.14', value: 45 },
    { name: '11A.1C.15', value: -12 },
    { name: '99R.963/5C-134-23' },
    { name: '11A.2C.18', value: 37 },
    { name: '11A.2C.17', value: 37 },
    { name: '11A.1C.9', value: 37 },
    { name: 'AAA.BBB.CCC', value: 37 },
    { name: 'F1.8C.10-1', value: 37 },
    { name: '99R.963/5C-134-23-94', value: 37 }
]*/
    deferred.resolve(sort(toOrder));
});
            
function sort(lista) {
    lista.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a.name > b.name) { return 1; }
        if (a.name < b.name) { return -1; }
        return 0;
      });

      return lista;
}
```

Everything works fine, until the moment the result is sent to the "resolve". That's when the order is lost again.
I need help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using `$q.defer` when working with `.then` blocks. Instead return values to create new promises:

```
var requests = $q.all([getValue1(obj), getValue2(obj)]);

var newPromise = requests.then(function (values) {
    var sortedValues = sort(values);
    return sortedValues;
});
```

The [array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method sorts [in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm). It is wise to make a copy before sorting:

```
function sort(lista) {
    var copiedLista = lista.concat();
    copiedLista.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a.name > b.name) { return 1; }
        if (a.name < b.name) { return -1; }
        return 0;
    });
    return copiedLista;
}
```

Then extract the values from the new promise:

```
newPromise.then(function(sortedValues) {
    console.log(sortedValues);
};
```